# Plotting pie char using ggplot2 in Shiny with input$ variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, pie-chart

I am building a Shiny app that helps user to create pie chart with ggplot2 on their own. Therefore, it would have a selector input for user to select variables from different dataframes. I was stuck with the `input$` statements, it seemed that Shiny took the `input$` with **double quotes** as a character, instead of a variable. Below is a simplified version of code, kindly let me know how to fix this. Thanks in advance!

```
library(ggplot2)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$var_selector <- renderUI({
    selectInput('var_selector', 'Please select:', choices = names(mtcars))
  })

  output$pie_plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(1), fill = factor(input$var_selector))) + geom_bar(width = 1) + coord_polar(theta = "y")
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    print(input$var_selector)
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h3('ggplot2 pie chart'),
      uiOutput('var_selector')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('pie_plot')
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Did you check whether `choices = names(mtcars)` works as expected? Usually `choices` expects a named list.

Comment: And then if this works as expected, the value of `input$var_selector` is a chr. So it's in quotes. `ggplot::aes` expects unquoted variables. So, you should use `aes_string` here.

Comment: Hi @mRcSchwering, the choices works as expected. I switched `aes` to `aes_string` but it still does not work.

Comment: Oh, because of the `factor` probably. Go back to `aes` and just use `mtcars[[input$var_selector]]` instead of `input$var_selector`

Comment: Thanks, it worked!